# Using the lm or dylm function in R to regress variables of different frequencies

Tags: r, parameters, linear-regression

I was wondering if it is possible to use dylm or lm function to regress for example a quarter on a monthly variable. When I try to do this the lm function states that the variable lengths differ. Which they of course do. Is there any way to bypass this without performing manual linear regression?

Example:

```
yt1 = rnorm(10, mean =10, sd = 1)
xt1 = rnorm(40, mean = 1,sd = 1)
lm(yt1 ~ xt1)
```

With yielding the following error.

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = yt1 ~ xt1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'xt1')
```

What approach should I take to regress variables of different lengths without using aggregation or disaggregation of the data?

Comment: Do you want `yt1` to recycle to the length of `xt1`?

Answer (score 0):

In R you can fit a linear model in this way

fit linear model,

```
linearmodel <- lm( y ~ x, data = dt)
```

summary of the full linear model,

```
summary(linearmodel)
```

Comment: I do not fully understand your approach. In my case, I have a variable yt which is observed at a lower frequency than the xt variable. In the same period I observe 10 values of yt and 40 of xt. Hence a quarterly monthly mismatch. Then I want to regress yt from xt but the variable length differ.

Comment: you have a data set with name dt which the first column is called x and the second one called y. So, make a data frame first and then apply my code into your variables. Hope this is helpful.